# Create a macro that would hide and show columns based on selection from a dropdown

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am totally new to the world of macros but have done some VBScript on QTP before. I am looking to create a macro which would hide certain columns depending on the users selection from a drop down. I am unsure of the syntax and how to identify the columns I wish to hide and how to identify the cell with the drop-down.

Here's roughly how I would see it looking -

```
Sub HideColumns()
    If cell(ViewType).Value = "Option 1" Then
       Cells(Column_1, Column_2).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf cell(ViewType).Value = "Option 2" Then
       Cells(Column_2, Column_3).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf cell(ViewType).Value = "Option 3" Then
       Cells(Column_3, Column_4).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I have named the cell with the drop-down `ViewType` in Excel - would the VBA recognize the object that way, or would I need to declare it?

How do I identify the columns I wish to hide?

Answer (score 1):

The names you define in Excel are available in Excel as normal variables, so this should not be of any issue.

In your case, I would however suggest using a `Switch Case` statement. This would look as follows:

```
Select Case ActiveWorkbook.Names("ViewType").RefersToRange
         Case "Option 1" 
              ' Hide Column X
         Case "Option 2" 
              ' Hide Column Y
End Select
```

Also keep in mind that for the macro to be called once you change a cell, you would need to put this code into

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub
```

This Sub has to be placed in the code part of the Sheet itself and will be executed every time a cell is changed in the Sheet.

Let me know if this is enough for you to go on or if you require more help.

Comment: Thanks Trefex - I will give that a go. 

I'm assuming that

Cells(A1, B1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True 

would hide columns A and B as they contain cells A1 an B1. Ideally I would get this to work based on a named cell to identify the comn to be hidden. Gonna give this a try right away.

Thanks again!

Comment: Seeing how Cells(R,C) relates more to a single cell, you'd rather use Range("A1:B1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True to hide Column A and B.

Let me know,

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Custom Views when hiding and unhiding columns.  Custom views is on the View tab (>=2007) and under the View menu (<=2003).  Here's an example:

1. Hide columns 1 and 2
2. View - Custom Views - Add - name it "Option1"
3. Unhide, then hide columns 2 and 3
4. View - Custom Views - Add - name it "Option2"
5. Unhide, then hide columns 3 and 4
6. View - Custom Views - Add - name it "Option3"
7. Unhide
8. Create Data Validation in a cell (that doesn't get hidden) and make is a List with "Option1, Option2, Option3"
9. Name that cell ViewType
10. Right click on the sheet tab and choose View Code and put the below code in that code pane

    ```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        'Only work on the cell named ViewType
        'The Me keyword refers to the sheet whose code module you're in
        If Target.Address = Me.Range("ViewType").Address Then
            'Show the custom view that corresponds to the value selected
            'in the dropdown
            ActiveWorkbook.CustomViews(Target.Value).Show
        End If

    End Sub
    ```

When the user selection Option1 from the drop down, the Option1 view is shown that hides columns 1 and 2.  It's a nice way to manage hiding and unhiding because you can just adjust the Custom View if you ever want to change it, rather than editing the code.